# How to force screen update for list view from non-UI thread (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, multithreading, listview, callback, notifications

I have a **background thread** listening to network, using a **callback** to process and store data. When it's ready (UI) controller gets a sync **Notification**, requests data, updates list and refreshes screen ...except **screen doesn't update** - until user scrolls the screen!

```
void aMessageArrivedCBack (const std::string text)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSString *msg = [[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:(const char *)text.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    [[AMessageStore sharedInstance] aStoreMessage:msg];
    [pool drain];

    [[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:NOTIF_MessageReceived object:nil];
}
```

Here's the (UI) controller routine for Notification handling, the problem area:

```
- (void)aMessageWasReceived:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [self.msgListView reloadData];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    [pool drain];
}
```

**Question:** how can I force screen update, when new message arrives? I have tried so many things I've lost count.. and just found out I'm trying same old things for fifth time. Still doesn't work.

**What I already tried:**

*Note: "didn't work" below means that screen didn't update.*

Data callback is running in non-UI thread, thus Notification is sent & received also in non-UI thread. Distributed notification are not available in iPhone OS, cannot use **NSDistributedNotificationCenter**.

[self.view **setNeedsDisplay**] and [self.msgListview setNeedsDisplay] don't work. Didn't really expect, not any more...

[self.msgListView **performSelectorOnMainThread**:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; really should work, it didn't. I couldn't find object to send it to, I recall. At least "self" didn't work: unrecognized selector sent to instance at 0x14036f0. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'. Self.msgListView works, but doesn't update screen.

[self.msgListView **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths**:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop]; didn't work.

[self.msgListView **insertRowsAtIndexPaths**:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop]; didn't work

[self.msgListView **visibleCells**]; works ok, but what to do with it?

I am positive it's a small thing to fix, but I just can't find it.. Is there any ways to kick the (nice) UI thread or tableView for update? Could I call some **_tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath** or anything? Can I do anything with **appDelegate**? How could I emulate "user scrolls the screen" event myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I do this in my apps I set a delegate for the background thread to send `performSelectorOnMainThread:...` to.

performSelectorOnMainThread is really the way to go here, most of those other things you list that you have tried do not work.

When you want to update a tableview you send it `reloadData` and it will in turn send `setNeedsDisplay` for the view to update. Have you tried that?

Comment: Got it working, just like you said. Tried to do that several times, but "something" was always a bit wrong. The final trick which helped me to get it all together was this line of code to print Thread ID in debugger console NSLog(@"Thread %d", pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_self()));

Comment: I am facing the same situation as urs. Can u plz say where do I have to use this line?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `-aMessageWasReceived:` is issued in a non-UI thread, and it contains code that attempts to update the UI.

Try performing that method (or its UI-updating contents in a separate method) on the main thread, instead, to get the UI to update in a timely fashion.

Comment: Knew these already, but didn't quite manage to make it clear in the question. Next time I'll try to write better description... Anyway, many thanx for support!